# How to connect ElasticSearch without creating model

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I researched on ElasticSearch and knew how to connect it but I need to create a model using anotation `@Document()` like this.

```
@Document(indexName = "resource", type = "person", shards = 1, replicas = 0)
public class Person {

@Id
private String id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

}
```

I create a Repository accordingly:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Person ,Long> {   }
```

My purpose is that I don't want create model anymore. I want to use Json file instead so my repository should be like this:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<String,Long> {    }
```

My problem is that I don't know the configuration of ElasticSearch in order to create indexName and type without using `@Document()`. I wonder if my idea is possible. I hope everyone can give me some hints. I really appreciate your supports. Thank you very much in advance.

This is my current configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:elasticsearch.properties")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "spring.demo")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

@Resource
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
    String host = environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host");
    int port = Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port"));
    String cluster = environment.getProperty("cluster.name");

    Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", cluster)
            .build();
    Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
             .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
    return client;
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
}
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html

Comment: Do you specifically want to use Spring Data Elasticsearch and connect without any data model? It would be not right since Spring Data projects are meant for repository and custom object-mapping abstractions. As suggested by @DarshanMehta, use native Elasticsearch Java client.